# How can we deny certain HTTP methods in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, web-config, filtering

I would like to disable HTTP methods in `web.config` but i couldn't do it. I just would like to enable `GET` & `POST` methods. Tried like this:

```
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
       <verbs allowUnlisted="false" applyToWebDAV="true">
          <clear/>
          <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
          <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
          <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="false" />
          <add verb="TRACE" allowed="false"/>
          <add verb="TRACK" allowed="false"/>
          <add verb="HEAD" allowed="false"/>
          <add verb="PROPFIND" allowed="false"/>
          <add verb="PUT" allowed="false"/>
          <add verb="COPY" allowed="false"/>
          <add verb="LOCK" allowed="false"/>
          <add verb="UNLOCK" allowed="false"/>
          <add verb="PROPPATCH" allowed="false"/>
          <add verb="MKCOL" allowed="false"/>
          <add verb="MOVE" allowed="false"/>
          <add verb="DELETE" allowed="false"/>
          <add verb="SEARCH" allowed="false"/>
        </verbs>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

Am I doing something wrong? I've search a lot but what do you prefer for disabling this verbs?

Comment: Please do not put a title in ALL CAPS. Or write entire sentences in all caps in most circumstances. All Caps is usually considered to be yelling at someone.

Comment: sorry about that @mason i was trying to fix it but i saw you already did that.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little hunch, can you try removing applytoWebDAV attribute and see?

```
<requestFiltering>
  <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
    <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
  </verbs>
</requestFiltering>
```

I think WebDAV extension module may have something to do with it. Usually if you go to IIS and Request Filtering, you can allow/deny verbs. It ultimately generates the same config file you mentioned.

Comment: I tried and seems working on browser but when i tested result is like that: https://s27.postimg.org/onep125gz/status.jpg